# how to create a document with multiple chapters

Tags: chapters

[image]I am very new in latex and winedt. I want to create thesis in winedt with 
 4 different chapters. but I don't know how to add chapters in main.tex file. how to add text in those files and then add them in main. say I want to name a chapter " introduction " and then add that in main.tex. like main.tex is the main file and then others are the subpart of this.

sorry if my question is very obvious, i am using this for the first time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Well, you simply have to write a main.tex file with your preamble and, in the body of the document,  say, `\input{intro}`. Of course you have to write , in the same directory, an `intro.tex` file. Preferably, create a dedicated directory, say ‘Mythesis\’, and don't forget to give a name to your project via the Project menu, and to declare `main.tex` as the main file of the project (`Set Main file in the Project menu).

Comment: @Bernard thank you so much for replying. I did that (setting the main file and all) but now I don't know how to add or create chapter files under main.tex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to create a new .tex file in WinEdt:
Click on the leftmost icon (named `New`) in the toolbar, and select ‘TeX file’, like this:
[image]

This opens an editing window and, when you save the file, just give the name, the extension `.tex` will be automatically appended.

Comment: @bernad thank you. I have edited my post and added an image. now I am confused. how to add sub.tex under main.tex or how to get the file of sub which is under the TOC

Comment: In `main.tex`, after `\begin{document}`, just add the command `\input{sub.tex}`, and similarly for other files you want to add. Of course, `sub.tex` will have no preamble (any  such code must go in the preamble of `main.tex`` . To see `sub.tex` and other files under `main.tex` in the toc, and update when you add or remove a file, click on the ‘tree’ icon in the tool bar.

Comment: @bernad thank you so much .now the file {sub} is under the main.tex but my project is not responding

Comment: another thing when ever i create a new a new project. it is now showing anything.

Comment: @ayesha You really need to read an introduction to LaTeX. There is no way to avoid it.

Comment: @ayesha: What do you mean with ‘it is not showing anything’? Did you type  a full code in `main.tex` (with preamble, `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`) , a code in `sub.tex`, and did you compile?